# Calling clustered EJB (WildFly) from the remote standalone client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, wildfly

Good day, I have a problem with understanding what is required (including server configurations) to successfully call EJB located in cluster from a standalone remote java client. So far I've tried both official guides from jboss and so far my solution works only partially.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/WildFly+9+Cluster+Howto
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

Currently on the client side I am using "client bom" maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Initial context for JNDI lookup is populated with next data:

```
    Properties env = new Properties();

    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://somehost:8080");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "client");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "clientPassword");
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    env.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
```

All EJBs are marked with @Stateless, @Clustered and  @Remote annotations.
If I am using the above config with a common deployment (not a clustered one), everything works fine and just as intended. However, if I try to connect to one of my cluster instances I am getting next response (where "backend2" is one of the two instances in cluster):

```
[INFO] | 19:26:35.838 | [THREAD: ejb-client-cluster-node-connection-creation-3-thread-1 | CLASS: org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionClusterNodeManager] -> Could not create a connection for cluster node ClusterNode{clusterName='ejb', nodeName='master:backend2', clientMappings=[ClientMapping{sourceNetworkAddress=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0, sourceNetworkMaskBits=0, destinationAddress='172.31.28.21', destinationPort=8280}], resolvedDestination=[Destination address=172.31.28.21, destination port=8280]} in cluster ejb
java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.IoFutureHelper.get(IoFutureHelper.java:94) ~[jboss-ejb-client-2.1.4.Final.jar:2.1.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:80) ~[jboss-ejb-client-2.1.4.Final.jar:2.1.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionManager.getConnection(RemotingConnectionManager.java:51) ~[jboss-ejb-client-2.1.4.Final.jar:2.1.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionClusterNodeManager.getEJBReceiver(RemotingConnectionClusterNodeManager.java:79) [jboss-ejb-client-2.1.4.Final.jar:2.1.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ClusterContext$EJBReceiverAssociationTask.call(ClusterContext.java:469) [jboss-ejb-client-2.1.4.Final.jar:2.1.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ClusterContext$EJBReceiverAssociationTask.call(ClusterContext.java:443) [jboss-ejb-client-2.1.4.Final.jar:2.1.4.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_92]
```